# Simple for-loop countdown timer in C

Tags: c, for-loop, cygwin, countdown, countdowntimer

This is what the code should do:

> “Lift off in T minus
>  5
>  4
>  3
>  2
>  1
>  Blast-off!”

When I run it, it just keeps printing ''Sum = 5'' forever.

Code:

```
int main(void) {

int sum = 5;  
int i;     

printf("Lift off in T minus\n");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i=i+i) {
    sum = sum - i;  
    printf("sum = %d\n",sum);  
} 

printf("Blast-off",sum);  

return 0;
```

Comment: you need to do `sum--;` to get 5,4,3,2,1

Comment: @Himanshu why is that?

Comment: @Himanshu what is your point?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ditto.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, check my answer, why i am suggesting `sum--` or `sum = sum -1;` instaed of `sum = sum - i;`

Comment: if i=0 and sum=5    ->     i = i+i = 0, so sum - i = is always 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i=i+i) { // use i = i+1
    sum = sum - i;       //sum-- or sum = sum -1
    printf("sum = %d\n",sum);  
}
```

As initially i=0, so

```
i=i+i; //will be zero always, no increment.
```

And

```
sum = sum -1;
```

otherwise

```
i = 0  =>sum = sum - i;    // = 5 as i=0
i = 1  =>sum = sum - i;    // = 4 as i=1
i = 2  =>sum = sum - i;    // = 2 as i=2
i = 3  =>sum = sum - i;    // = -1 as i=3
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not run the loop backwards?

```
for (i = 5; i > 0; --i) {
    printf("i = %d\n",i);  
}
```

This is simpler so the potential for bugs to creep in is reduced. Also, your final `printf` if malformed: you're missing a format specifier for `sum`.

Your *specific* problem: replace `i=i+i` with `i=i+1` or something similar. (I prefer `++i`).